# Issue with date conversion in SAS

Tags: datetime, sas

I have a bizarre situation where I have dates as characters, such as 06/May/2014.  I'm converting them to SAS dates as follows:

```
data ae;
    set ae;
    format aestdt date10.;
    aestdt=input(aestdat,date9.);
    put aestdt=YYMMDD10.;
run;
```

What I get for the output variable is changing the year of the date from 2014 to 2020.  So in the example above, I get  06MAY2020.  All of the months and days look correct, so I can't figure out why the years are changing on me.  Any ideas?

Comment: Use compress function to remove / from the date first. Input(compress(aestdat, '/'), date9.)

Comment: @Reese why do you need to do that?  One major advantage of SAS is its willingness to do things like that for you!

Comment: Too many drugs in my system is my excuse ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you brought it in as `date9.`.  The `9` in an informat means `how many characters do we look at to create this number?`.  `06/MAY/2014` has not 9 but 11 characters.

```
data ae;
    aestdat='06/MAY/2014';
    format aestdt date10.;
    aestdt=input(aestdat,date11.);
    put aestdt=YYMMDD10.;
run;
```

This gives the expected result.